# Why is my mouse randomly deselecting and unclicking?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

(Windows 7 x64, Logitech MX1100 mouse)

If I click/hold/ the mouse, like on the title bar of a folder to move it, or to select text, the mouse will randomly "unselect" it and then randomly reselect at another point in the movement.

For example, if I were to start mouse-selecting the above paragraph, starting with "movement." and then moving backwards, it might select as far as "reselect", but then the selection would disappear, only to start selecting again from "will randomly".

I realize this would sound like a clear-cut case for a hardware issue in the mouse button, but I've narrowed out that that's not the case. The problem doesn't happen if I drag-move/drag-select slowly. But I can make the problem very apparent if I click and drag something fast. For example, if I click and hold the title bar of a window, and then start quickly dragging it around in circles across my monitor, the window will get "dropped", and a new window will get picked up in the process.

Additionally, if I right-click anywhere to get a context menu (in Windows, programs, anywhere/everywhere), and then relatively quickly press the left mouse button to select something on the context menu, the context menu will disappear as if I had clicked "through" it.

I haven't had any driver changes, system updates, or significant software changes/updates/installations recently, that might be a precursor to this issue. Again, the oddity seems to be the "speed" of action.

Another note -- it seems that "lag" has a bit to do with it. If I click and drag a window around quickly, it might start to "lag" a tad bit, like it's perhaps moving too fast for Windows to keep up with the refresh/redraw rate, and that's usually synonymous with this odd deselect bug happening.

(Batteries fully charged, no damage or recent changes to mouse, no changes that might affect/block wireless communication)

EDIT:

If I click and hold on something, like a folder in Windows Explorer, it sees it as a double-click. Yet, if I just click and let go once, it doesn't follow through like a double-click (I thought maybe the single-click link-behavior might have been inadvertently activated).

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse? Have you tried plugging the receiver into a different USB port? Have you added any new devices to your computer that connects over USB (or in general)?

Comment: As sidran said, try a different mouse. I had a mouse left button go bad on me and it exhibited almost the same issues you've described.

Comment: I agree with the hardware issue. On a slightly bad button, it will often work fine on slow speed - but when we move the mouse faster the pressure points changes on the button, which may trigger more sensitivity problems. If the mouse is still on warranty, it's highly advised to try another mouse so you can address it as soon as possible.

Comment: I certainly would try a different mouse (and a different USB port) before I looked for other causes.  Also, if this is a laptop I'd want to be sure that your other hand wasn't resting on the touchpad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, the problem's disappeared before I could further diagnose :/  But if/when it returns, I'll swap mouses.

Comment: I have a Logitech Bluetooth travel mouse for my Samsung Ultrabook and I have seen the behaviour you describe come up in the last few weeks. Most annoying. I recently put in fresh batteries, so these should still be good. USB cannot be the problem, touchpad is switched off. So probably hardware failure. Plugging in a USB mouse, I find the problem goes away. So, I'll be shopping for another bluetooth mouse soon. Thanks @BenRichards!!

Comment: I am having this exact same problem with my Logitech Performance MX and was wondering if you bought another one or if they replaced yours.

Comment: I had the very same issue with my wired Logitech M500. I really love the way it fits my hand, but this annoying "jumps" when selecting text were killing me. Interestingly, I had a USB 3.0 hub and a monitor in between the connection of the mouse... obviously not the most sound solution possible as it turned out. So connecting the mouse directly to PC resolved my issue. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I have had problems like this before on a wireless mouse. I had to change to corded mouse.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a hardware issue. I posted some questions so you can help clarify your situation, but the reason this happens could be because (in order from most likely to least likely):

If you're on a laptop, input from both the external mouse and internal touchpad can interfere with each other. If there are mulitple pointing devices connected, it also can cause strange behavior. Windows wasn't designed to accept competing input from two mouse pointing devices at the same time and be able to deal with each separately. So if something is accidentally bumping the touchpad or something else while you're trying to do something with the mouse, it might cause things like you describe to occur.

Your mouse button is starting to go. Because of their constant use, it's likely that they'll be the first to go due to wear. The contacts might be a bit finnicky and have become sensitive to nearly indetectible changes in pressure on the button. Different behavior while using the mouse in different ways might cause misclicks. The behavior might be beyond whatever [debouncing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debouncing#Contact_bounce) the circuitry in the mouse is able to do.

The battery could be losing its charge. If it's a rechargeable battery, it's good to note that they do tend deteriorate over time. It should take a while before it causes an issue, but it can happen somewhat quickly if you tend to overcharge the battery. Even if it reports being fully charged, it still may not be providing enough power to maintain reliable communication with the computer.

Your wireless signal might be getting interference. Perhaps another device could be interfering with the wireless communication between the receiver and the mouse. Even if the device doesn't transmit, they still can emit EM interference and cause other devices to behave erratically. But if you have something else in the vicinity that transmits on the same frequency and by chance is being picked up by the wireless receiver, it might be confusing the two devices, similar to trying to use two different remote controls to control the same TV at once.

Your USB receiver for the mouse might be malfunctioning. If it gets unplugged, stored, transported, and replugged-in quite a bit, it's possible that it experienced wear to the point that it began malfunctioning. Storage in excessive heat or cold can also cause damage to electronic components (same goes with the mouse itself).

The USB port you're using could be faulty. This isn't an unheard of situation. Perhaps the USB root hub isn't working correctly because it's misconfigured. Checking the Device Manager can help you determine if this is a problem or not. Or, there could be a physical problem with the port itself. Since they get a ton of use, especially with devices like this, wear can occur and there might be a broken solder connection, or bent pin, that isn't connecting reliably and interrupting USB communication with the device.

Or, you could be having conflicts with other USB devices on your machine. This doesn't tend to be the issue these days, as operating systems these days are very good at managing USB devices. However, there's always potential for a rare case to happen that causes issues. Again, the Device Manager can report if there are any resource conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Unfortunately, the problem "seems" to have disappeared; at least, temporarily. I'll keep an eye out for it repeating, and will continue diagnosing with your tips above. Thanks!

Comment: @Coldblackice Good luck!

Comment: PS - Just for reference, it actually was a matter of the button switch physically deteriorating. The mouse has been replaced, and now all is well! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to fix the physical switch? This is a common problem, every mouse I ever had usually shows first signs of upcoming death when left click starts to misclick, imporoperly register pressure... Asking because every time, after so many years I am attached and used to my mouse, would rather fix than replace with new model I have to get used to.

Comment: @Carmageddon That depends on the particular mouse and whether you can open it up without breaking it, and whether you can find replacement switches online for it. I've never attempted this, personally.

Answer (score 12):

**To eliminate the fact that it's not a TOO NEW DRIVER issue:**

- uninstall your updated driver, reboot, then **install the driver that came with your mouse.**

The driver that is sold with the mouse MUST work and is error checked.
Newer versions can be become incompatible with older hardware, as new features are added gradually. I doubt they test it with ALL previous hardware - they test it with some, and they suppose it works with the rest.

**To verify it is not a BUTTON HARDWARE issue:**

- **swap the mouse buttons** in the driver (most software have an option for this, for left handed users).

The left mouse button is supposed to be less used, and if it works properly, it's a very high chance it's a button hardware issue. If it shows the same erratic movement, it's a different problem. In case:

- Microswitch is defective --> change it
- Solder joints got defective over time --> resolder it

See this post for instructions: http://www.kaibader.de/logitech-m705-how-to-fix-a-defective-mouse-button/

Comment: Swapping the mouse button is a damn good idea ! I was able t confirm this is indeed a hardware issue with my left button.

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this same problem as well and it is a nightmare.  I'm a software architect/engineer so I work on computers all day.

Two things I have narrowed down that have both caused this are

1)  Interferance from another device:  I actually had one of those portable foot massagers under my desk.  The type that has two rotational wheel with balls on them that massaged bottom of your feet.  I determined that when I had that thing on somehow the electronic signal caused my mouse to act sporatic...it was crazy.  So that was an easy one..I've also seen fans some times cause an issue.

2)  It seems sometimes, especially when I've left my laptop idle for a longer period of time, days for example and it goes into hibernation that when I try to wake it up even after rebooting it seems to go on a LONG cycle of starting up, cleaning up etc.  When it does this it seems get into this same state where it almost seems like the CPU is literally falling behind when trying to do anything.  I've found after it eventually catches up the problem goes away.

Not saying this is your problem but these are definitely two I've found to occur.

Answer (score 2):

Just experienced this symptom with a Logitech MX510 that I thought would outlive me. Changing to another mouse, problem gone. Trying the MX510 on another laptop, problem persists. So it's hardware. Will try to open and clean it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem on M720. It's too expensive just to dump the mouse and it has hardly been 10 months for me. Being a Logitech fan I was not expecting this issue to come this early, since I have used quite older mice but none had this issue.

On closer inspection it seems like there is debris stuck under the "click" button. I am not sure if there's a guide to cleaning mice but I am going to vaccum/dry everything out of it.

Comment: I had this exact same issue and it was driving me mad, happened to have this version and as you say I blew some compressed air under it and the problem seemed to go away.