# Mouse button hold unreliable on Razer DeathAdder left hand edition

Tags: mouse

When holding the left or right mouse button on my Razer DeathAdder, it intermittently stops to register the hold. For example, when I move a Windows window, it only moves a bit and then drops. I have been using the mouse without this problem for over a year and it recently occurred without me changing neither software settings nor installing new hardware.

I use a Razer DeathAdder left hand mouse with "3500DPI Razer Precision 3,5G infrared sensor", Model number RZ01-00151700-W1M1 on Windows 10 with the legacy driver. I don't use the Synapse driver though it regularily asks me to install it which I always decline, I hope it doesn't install something without my permission.

**Is this a software problem or a hardware problem and how can I get my mouse button hold to work reliably again?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor are notorious ([1](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/tech-support/240980-razer-death-adder-mouse-troubles))([2](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2762820/razer-deathadder-click-drag-scroll-wheel-issues.html))([3](http://www.overclock.net/t/1425051/razer-deathadder-3500-left-click-button-faulty))(+Personal experience) For the clickers on their mice.

There is an answer from [Ben Richards](https://superuser.com/questions/518084/why-is-my-mouse-randomly-deselecting-and-unclicking) Which covers the reasons why. The short version being:

- Accidentally hitting a touchad
- Mouse button going (Usually the clicker) I personally had [double clicks](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=razer+imperator+click+fix) on my razer imperator when I was single clicking. Very handy for double tapping in an fps game, not so much at the desktop.
- Dirt, you may have gunge/dust under the mouse that is preventing solid contact. Try cleaning it if you can, lift up the buttons and get some compressed air in there. Don't snap it!
- Try swapping USB port
- Device conflicts (Not as likely in modern day OS's IRQs can be shared, but the operating system is usually good at preventing problems)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a lot like a "hardware problem" to me. I've had this behavior with several mice over the years.

It could be as simple as some hair or dust somehow keeping the contact from properly pushing the switch.

If you can, try to blow with air under the mouse buttons, possibly lifting them a bit while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% a hardware issue. The button held releases without you hearing a click. Bad hardware. I'm now on my third Adder Left hand edition with this problem.

The only fix to this problem is to forcefully hold down the button with you finger or to get a new mouse.